# Reading Excel file using SheetJs - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read Excel file using SheetJs

But getting following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

**Here is my file handler function**

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    //Get the files from Upload control
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var i, f;
    //Loop through files
    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            var data = evt.target.result;

            var result;
            /* convert from workbook to array of arrays */
            var first_worksheet = data.Sheets[data.SheetNames[0]];
            var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(first_worksheet, {header:1});
            alert(result[0].Column1);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to first **read this data as an XLSX** sheet first ([Refer page 11](http://sheetjs.com/docs.pdf))

```
workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
```

Followed by getting *sheetnames* from *workbook* (page 13)

```
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, have any idea about `It is converting large numbers like 3520000000000` into `3.52E+12` ?

Comment: @NomanAli Not sure, need to refer the docs for the same. I guess this is taking existing column setting from excel sheet.  Probably create a new question for the same if this one has solved the problem you had originally described.